# Macro definition of table name in \pgfplotstableread

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using pgfplots in a report to make similar plots for many different data sets, for each of which the data is included in a separate .txt file. I use \pgfplotstableread to read data tables and assign to a macro name for later use in the plots.

I would like to be able to define a command that takes one text string argument, and uses this argument to refer to both the data file and to name the table. I can not seem to get anything to work for defining the stored name of the table dynamically inside the macro (e.g. using \csname).

At its simplest, perhaps I just need to understand why \tablereadB in the following MWE produces an error? Here I assume there is a data.txt file to be read.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tablereadA}{ \pgfplotstableread{data.txt}{\tabA} }
\newcommand{\tablereadB}{ \pgfplotstableread{data.txt}{\csname tabB\endcsname} }

% this works:
\tablereadA{}

% this gives  error Extra \endcsname
\tablereadB{}

\end{document}
```

I am assuming this has something to do with the expansion order, but have not been able to get anything working using \expandafter.

---

As a follow up to gernot's answer, ultimately, for the string input "ONE", I would like the command to execute the equivalent of the following:

```
\pgfplotstableread{\pathONE}{\tabONE}
```

Here, \pathONE would be previously defined manually, among a long list of paths (one per data file). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\pgfplotstableread` stores the table under the given name. In your approach `\csname` is redefined and `tabB\endcsname` is left over, with `\endcsname` leading to the error message.

Try it this way:

```
\newcommand\tablereadB{\expandafter\tablereadBaux\csname tabB\endcsname}
\newcommand\tablereadBaux[1]{\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}{#1}}
```

Here is the solution for the follow-up question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand\tableread[1]%
  {\edef\tablereadX
     {\noexpand\pgfplotstableread
       {\csname path#1\endcsname}%
       \csname tab#1\endcsname
     }%
   \tablereadX
  }
\begin{document}
\newcommand\pathONE{data.txt}
\tableread{ONE} % expands to \pgfplotstableread {data.txt}\tabONE
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would I adapt this to allow macro input of both the data name and the resulting table name? That is, for the string input "ONE", I would like to be able to generate the effective output:

Comment: \pgfplotstableread{\pathONE}{\tabONE}